# How to query based on multiple conditions using switch case and derive new field based on result in aggregate mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to query my users collection based on course and I need to add one custom field i.e., status to my result. Really appreciate for the help.

My users Schema:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password1",
    feePaid: true
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "def",
    course: "python",
    password: "Password2",
    feePaid: true
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "xyz",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password3",
    feePaid: false
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "ghi",
    course: "java",
    feePaid: false
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    name: "lol",
    course: "java",
    password: "Passswwword",
    feePaid: false
  }
];
```

Logic for deriving Status:

1. NotRegistered: if password field is not present
2. Active : feePaid is true
3. Inactive: If feePaid is false

My query to fetch the users based on course and for deriving custom field - status

```
const allUsers = await users.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
           { course: "java" }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
             status: {
              $switch: {
                branches: [
                  { "case": { "$ifNull": [ "$password", false ] }, "then": "NotRegistered" },
                  { "case": { "$eq": [ "$feePaid", true ] }, "then": "Active" },
                  { "case": { "$eq": [ "$feePaid", false ] }, "then": "Inactive" }
                ],
                default: null
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Expected Result - Should contain respective status

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password1",
    feePaid: true,
    status: "Active"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "xyz",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password3",
    feePaid: false,
    status: "Inactive"

  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "ghi",
    course: "java",
    feePaid: false,
    status: "NotRegistered"

  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    name: "lol",
    course: "java",
    password: "Passswwword",
    feePaid: false,
    status: "Inactive"
  }
];
```

My result - I am getting all the status as null. Not sure why it is not entering the switch cases

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password1",
    feePaid: true,
    status: null
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "xyz",
    course: "java",
    password: "Password3",
    feePaid: false,
    status: null

  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "ghi",
    course: "java",
    feePaid: false,
    status: null

  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    name: "lol",
    course: "java",
    password: "Passswwword",
    feePaid: false,
    status: null
  }
];
```

Comment: there is no issue, Its working as per your expected result look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bcwGGgA-kI5)

Comment: Looks ok to me, the only thing I can see wrong is the `$match` pipeline step which seems to be having an extra pair of `{}` braces